# Use FB API to get the pages that a page likes?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been looking at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#fields) for the FB API as it pertains to pages to see if I can get the pages that given page likes and all I can see is a field that lets you get the number of users who like a given page. But, I can't seem to find a field that returns an array containing the ids and names of pages that the page itself likes. This works fine in the API explorer when trying to get the likes of a users.

I just use GET

```
/me?fields=likes
```

But, for a page... it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **page id**, instead of **me**:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/likes

Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=6815841748%2Flikes

Cheers

Comment: I'd accept your answer only it seems that after clicking your link, it seems that you're a raging socialist based upon your likes... just kidding.